# sessionmaker object has no attribute add

Tags: python, postgresql, fastapi

I am trying to insert data into postgresql server. While doing so, when I try to add the data into the SQLalchemy session, I am getting the error "sessionmaker object has no attribute add":

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
```

```
def create_new_user(user: UserCreate, db: Session):
    user=User(username= user.username,
        email=user.email,
        hashed_password= Hasher.get_password_hash(user.password),
        is_active=True,
        is_superuser=False
        )
    db.add(user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(user)
    return user
```

Comment: `Session` needs to be an instance -> `Session()`?

Comment: See [the docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-a-dependency) is you are trying to use FastAPI's dependency injection

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object from `Session` as show in this [example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#opening-and-closing-a-session); which uses a context-manager.

Currently, I use the [scoped_session](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/contextual.html) pattern (suitable for most web apps). Here is how my session initialization looks like:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Session() # --> returns the same object in the same thread
```